# Как добавить закладку сайта на дисплей телефона?

Tags: javascript, jquery, доступ

Как можно добавить закладку сайта на рабочий стол для быстрого доступа. Иконка выглядит как приложение и будет закреплена на главном экране пользователя.
При нажатии на эту иконку, открывается сайт в браузере. 
Как сделать такую кнопку на сайте (для мобильной версии) и что писать в коде?
Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут для такой задачи скорее всего подойдет применять [web manifest](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/).
Составляете его и подключаете просто в head. Как пример реализации можно посмотреть статью на [medium](https://medium.com/@franciov/how-to-make-your-web-app-installable-8b71571605e#.m9fc0ljpm)

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webmanifest">
```

Еще у Вадима Макеева был хороший доклад, про веб приложения, как нативные: [Ещё лучше, чем настоящие!](https://youtu.be/Bhd5HQ1I2LM)